# Issues with custom mysql docker image

Tags: mysql, docker

I have been trying to dockerize my node js application which utilizes mysqldb  for databses and I have been having issues as how to dockerize mysql . I want to build my custom docker image on top of mysql which when run create database and tables so that my node js application can use those databases and table . Below is the code of my custom mysql docker image

```
FROM mysql:5.7


ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD root
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE degreeclearencedatabase
ENV MYSQL_USER root
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD 123456

COPY ./sqlscripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/



EXPOSE 3306


CMD ["mysqld"]
```

and here are my sql scripts

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
first_name varchar(25),
last_name  varchar(25),
department varchar(15),
email  varchar(50)
);
```

While building this image I got following logs

```
root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
```

Now when I ran container of that custom image , I am unable to login to mysql and getting following error

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

I will be really grateful if someone helps me in identifying what mistakes I am doing in my docker file ?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please provide the `docker run` command you are using to run the mysql image?

Comment: Have you tried composition instead of lumping everything into one container? Typically [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) can be used with standard containers and images to achieve a custom application.  The Drupal chapter of the docker compose docs shows how to link a standard mysql container to the drupal container to create an application made of 2 containers.  While drupal is PHP and you want nodejs, the concerns (inter-container communications) and solutions (--link) are similar.